# Match only the result of a inverse regex

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to protect postfix (which is protected already, but.. you know..) because I saw from the logs that many domains try to log on it.

I use fail2ban for ssh already and I wanted to create a regex to match the bad domains and ban them.

All I know, is that everything coming from google and localhost is safe.
I am trying to invert this regex I created but I am having issues both in adding a localhost exception and exclude from the search "google" too.

You will find everything [HERE](http://regexr.com/3fhb9) at regexr(dot)com website.

I really appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**:
I wish I could mark both the answers as accepted. I am accepting the one I choose because this guy explained his regex in detail.
Though, my skills here are poor and I understand the other solution more.
Both of them works as intended, so thank you guys!

Comment: try with `\b(connect.from)(?!.*(localhost|google)).*`

Comment: That worked! I knew it was easy but couldn't get it. Please write it as answer that I can upvote (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you look for the following regular expression:

```
\b(connect\sfrom)\s(?!(.*?\.)?google)(?!localhost)[^\[]*
```

- `\s` represents a whitespace (this is narrower than your dot).
- `(.*?\.)?google` means match "google" or any "subdomain.google" combination. The question mark makes the regex non-greedy (as small as possible)
- `(?!A)(?!B)` is a Multiple Negative Lookahead. The essence of your question
- `[^\[]*` means match the longest possible ("greedy") string until '[' occurs.

**In short:** You look for `(?!A)(?!B)`

Comment: I am seriously impressed. Thanks! Just tried and works as it should (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use Negative Lookahead in middle of the string

```
\b(connect.from)(?!.*(localhost|google)).*
```